# Careers puts the wrong "Most recent" employment at the top of the profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, profile-page

On my profile page, I noticed that the "Most recently " line at the top of my profile was showing the incorrect entry in my employment history.

I figured that this must be because my most recent entry said "2006 - Current" and that the behavior must be because the date couldn't be determined.  So, I changed it to 2006 - 2011.  However, the entry from 2004 - 2006 remains at the top.  Is this a bug or is there something I am misunderstanding about the Careers profile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks, this should be resolved. Please have another look.

Comment: thank you.  It has been resolved on my profile.  (1) Was this a code error or was I doing something wrong?  (2) Does the date sorting support the string "Current", or do I need to type the current year to prevent strange behavior?

Comment: @smartcaveman it was a code error -- we weren't sorting correctly if some of your employment entries did not have a company specified.  Also, "Current" should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

You may

- manually change priority by clicking Up/Down arrows or
- choose TimeFrame->Display Options->Prevent this experience from appearing in header

Answer (score 1):

I have tried moving my experience sections up and down, but nothing seems to have any effect. In have one position at Bank of America in 2011, and the preceding one at Wells Fargo in 2008 - 2010, but the uneditable text near the top of my [profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit/13302) says "Most recently Senior Web Developer at Wells Fargo." That is wrong. No matter how you calculate it, my most recent experience is Bank of America.